# Sockets Python desconectar client

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Eu gostaria de fazer com que com um comando do *server*, fosse desconectado um *client* específico.

```
from socket import *



meuHost = ''


minhaPort = 50007


sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


sockobj.bind((meuHost, minhaPort))


sockobj.listen(5)


while True:
    conexão, endereço = sockobj.accept()                                       




    print('Server conectado por', endereço)

    while True:

        data = conexão.recv(1024)



        if not data: break

        conexão.send(b'Eco=>' + data)
```

Se há este atributo "Accept", há algum meio de se "Kickar" ou desconectar um client do meu server?

Comment: Python3 aceita variáveis com acento -- mas não quer dizer que você deva usa-las  ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou simplesmente `conexão.close()`?

Na verdade a documentação diz que para fechar imediatante você pode usar também o método `shutdown` antes do `close`:

```
conexão.shutdown()
conexão.close()
```

Comment: Mas no argumento () de conexão.close da para inserir um numero de ip especifico de um usuario para poder desconectar apenas aquele usuario?

Comment: A sua variável conexão, que é atribuida na linha ` conexão, endereço = sockobj.accept() ` se refere a uma única conexão (portanto, de um único usuário). Esse seu programa não "atende" a conexões simultâneas no socket. Um novo usuário só será respondido por esse código quando o `while` mais interno acabar e essa linha for executada de novo.

Para tratar conexões simultâneas, você tem que ter um programa que tenha uma estratégia de multi-threading, multi-processing ou assíncrona.

Comment: Programaçaõ direta em sockwts feita do jeito certo não é algo fácil. É importante para entender como funciona,aprender, etc... mas para produção, é melhor usar um protocolo de mais alto nível, com um servior de algum framework.